# How to keep Active remote Connections in MySQL Database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a java application which has remote access in an online MySQL Database, and it works fine.

The only problem is that after a few minutes, the connection to the server was closed, is there anyway to keep the connection active? So that I won't have to instantiate another connection just to perform the task.

Any ideas and inputs would be much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to auto reconnect, try editing your JDBC URL:

> jdbc:mysql://[host]:[port]/[database]?**autoReconnect=true**

See connector reference: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: I've updated my connection string to this: "jdbc:mysql://[host]:[port]/[database]?autoReconnect=true?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true";

but when i run my program there's an exception occurred saying that "The connection property 'autoReconnect' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'true?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true' is not in this set." 

any ideas about this one?

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have pointed out you can use the `autoReconnect` option on the connection to solve the immediate problem.

However, if you are not using a database connection pool I would *strongly* suggest that you switch to one.

They have a number of advantages:

- They check your connections for you - this deals with timeouts, network issues etc
- They control the number of connections
- You can simply 'close' the connection when your done with each bit of work and then 'reopen' a connection when needed.

If you manage connections yourself you will almost certainly end up writing some form of connection pool - and why reinvent the wheel.

By the time you have implemented connection checking so that they don't go stale, some sort of connection holder so that you don't need to re-open them each time, some sort of exception handling code you are well on your way to writing a lot of code that has already been written and thoroughly tested.

I have used [dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) and [boneCP](http://jolbox.com/) and both are very easy to use and configure and will save you hours and hours of frustration dealing with JDBC connection issues.

Comment: Thanks for that inputs, i'll consider that. Thank you guys.

Comment: +1 This is ideal approach for managing connections for moderate to heavy database intensive applications. Though for very occasional use or standalone testing program non-connection-pool approach can be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
jdbc:mysql://[host]:[port]/[database]?autoReconnect=true&user=root&password=passwordIchose
```